# WebHostBuilderExtensions.UseStartup and dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, grpc, worker-service

I am learning gRPC support in .NET. My goal is to implement a gRPC service hosted in .NET "Worker Service".

Based on the [this](https://celery94.github.io/grpc/netcore3.0/2019/05/30/net-core-3.0-worker-grpc/) tutorial now I have

in Program.cs:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseWindowsService(options => options.ServiceName = "GrpcGreeter Service")
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IServiceNeededForStartup, ServiceNeededForStartup>();
        services.AddHostedService<GreeterWorker>();
    })
    .Build()
    .Run();
```

in GreeterWorker.cs:

```
public class GreeterWorker : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        await Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddSingleton<IServiceNeededForStartup, ServiceNeededForStartup>())
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(builder => builder.UseStartup<Startup>())
            .Build()
            .StartAsync(stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

and in Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    //private readonly IServiceNeededForStartup serviceNeededForStartup;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration/*,
        IServiceNeededForStartup serviceNeededForStartup*/)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
        //this.serviceNeededForStartup = serviceNeededForStartup;
    }
```

, where `(I)ServiceNeededForStartup` is just my own C# interface and class.

This works fine until I try to get my `serviceNeededForStartup` injected in the `Startup` c'tor, i. e. when I uncomment commented code I'm getting

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
> Unable to resolve service for type 'GrpcGreeter.Services.IServiceNeededForStartup' while attempting to activate 'GrpcGreeter.Startup'.

Is this possible to have my `serviceNeededForStartup` injected?